# How to store form data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/','UserController@index');
Route::post('/index','UserController@store');
```

controller: UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Users;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new Users();
        $user->fname = $request->input('fname');
        $user->lname = $request->input('lname');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = $request->input('password');
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('index')->with('info','User Added Successfully');
    }
}
```

View:index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('title','Index Page')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form id="myform" action="{{route('store')}}">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">{{ trans('core.fname') }}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">{{ trans('core.lname') }}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">{{ trans('core.email') }}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">{{ trans('core.password') }}</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="{{trans('core.submit')}}"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

I am new in laravel. In this code I am simply want to perform CRUD operation. Here only I am performing insert operation but it show me an error i.e.

> Route [store] not defined. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\resources\views\index.blade.php).

I am not getting where I am doing wrong? So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: I am changing `Route::post('/','UserController@store')` to `Route::post('/','UserController@store')->name("store")` but data not save in table

Comment: whats your model name ? a

Comment: model name is `Users.php` @VikasKatariya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change in your `web.php`

```php
Route::post('/index','UserController@store')->name('store');
```

add `method="POST"` in your form which is **missing**

```php
@extends('layout.main')
@section('title','Index Page')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form id="myform" action="{{route('store')}}" method="post">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">{{ trans('core.fname') }}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">{{ trans('core.lname') }}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">{{ trans('core.email') }}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fname">{{ trans('core.password') }}</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="{{trans('core.submit')}}"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Route::post('/index','UserController@store')->name('index.store');
```

and on your blade file

```
route('index.store')
```

see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

**Change this Perfectly work:-**

```
Route::post('/index','UserController@store')->name('store');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request,[
            'fname' => 'required',
            'lname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = new Users();
        $user->fname = $request->fname;
        $user->lname = $request->lname;
        $user->email = $request->email;
         $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->save();
        Toastr::success('User Successfully Saved','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.user.index');
}
```